# What is difference between gatsby and strapi?

Tags: reactjs, web, gatsby, strapi

I have a little bit confusion about difference between strapi and gatsby.

Is it good to use both of them together or to choose one of them?

If they are used together how they work together (the mechanism behind)?

When and in which case to use them together?

Answer (score 1):

Strapi is a headless CMS and it's used in the backend side of things, while Gatsby is a frontend framework that is very good for SEO as it servers static html pages and it's very friendly with the google web-crawlers.

I personally haven't used Strapi but I have create 2 projects with Gatsby and I can say it's a good framework and if you know React.js you can easily learn Gatsby.